# Two stability of normal random variable detailed explanation

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I am reading about two stability of normal random variable and I am super confused (no good background in stats or calc), but I really need to understand it. Please, see the following:
[image]

I first got stuck on "By definition, $f_z(z) = \int f_x(z-y)\ f_y(y) dy$"

Could someone explain me how we get $f_z$ ? I do not really understand the intuition behind the integral. I am further confused about the computation. It would be great if you could show me intermediate steps of this computation (integral) so I can follow. I will really appreciate!

Comment: It is a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) (the keyword might help): summing independent random variables corresponds to doing a convolution of their probability density functions.

Comment: I'm a little disturbed that the "claim" fails to mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @ClementC. thanks for the reference!